# Kernal does not detect type SSD

Tags: 14.04, ssd

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and this system is connected with SSD (No HDDS just SSD). When i check "cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational" it shows 1. It doesn't seem to recognize the type of drive is SSD. Any help here is appreciated how do i tell kernal that it is an SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this page

http://lwn.net/Articles/408428/

via this page

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372544/what-is-the-significance-of-queue-rotational-in-linux

It says that there's a kernel parameter you can pass to set it. You'll have to figure out which one though. Once you do, edit `/etc/default/grub` accordingly.

FWIW, it's not the end of the world if your box things your ssd is an hdd. It just means the kernel will spend a little more cpu trying to avoid seeks. seeks are cheap for ssds, so this doesn't matter, but you should still get most of the benefit of an ssd whether the kernel knows it or not.