# Why is my SSD device recognized as an HDD?

Tags: ssd, sata

I have Linux server running Ubuntu 18.04.5 with kernel version `Linux myserver 5.4.0-66-generic #74~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 11:17:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux'`.

And I have SSD device installed on the system. But the command output shows it is HDD.
What should I do to change this properly?

#### FROM the operational mode, I can see this is SSD.

```
Name  Solid State Disk 0:1:2 
Bus Protocol  SATA 
Media Type  SSD 
State  Online 
Size  1787.88 GB 
Used RAID Disk Space  1787.88 GB
```

#### From the Ubuntu OS, it recognized as HDD, eg, `1` from rotational;

```
# lsblk -d -o name,rota
NAME  ROTA
loop0    1
sda      1
sdb      1
sdc      1
sr0      1
```

```
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
1
# cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/rotational
1
# cat /sys/block/sdc/queue/rotational
1
```

Additional info.

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 1919716163584 bytes, 3749445632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x98bff556

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3749445631 3749443584  1.8T 83 Linux
```

```
# /etc/fstab

/dev/disk/by-uuid/da4c4f67-67ad-4775-8bc9-22401cbca7e9 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0

# /srv was on /dev/sdb1
UUID=2a812ea1-4cd3-4c20-9b58-60b9efd4543a /srv ext4 defaults 0 0

# /data was on /dev/sdc1
UUID=f8457ea1-09f8-416e-9bd3-361cf3a5229a /data ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: I don't see your issue. It's recognized as a solid state drive/disk.

Comment: "Used RAID Disk Space  1787.88 GB"? I don't see evidence of MD/RAID here, so what RAID controller are you using? That might mess with the detection.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question. The Ubuntu rotational value is 1 even if it is SSD. It should be 0 as I googled.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/647003/kernal-does-not-detect-type-ssd